# Interceptor has no bindings

Tags: quarkus

When certain values are changed in my classes, I want to fire an event on the vertx event bus to alert an observing class. Instead of hand coding every setter, I am trying to create an interceptor and annotation on certain fields so that when they are set, the interceptor can send the event.

However, I get the error when I start quarkus dev - "Interceptor has no bindings: com.delta.DMNChangedInterceptor"

Here is my code:

```java
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@Inherited
public @interface DMNChanged {
}
```

```java
@Priority(2020)
@Interceptor
public class DMNChangedInterceptor {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @DMNChanged
    @AroundInvoke
    Object logInvocation(final InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        Log.info("Inoking DMNChanged");
        final Object ret = context.proceed();
        Log.info("Completed DMNChanged");
        return ret;
    }

}
```

I can't see anything that is different from the  example in the Quarkus docs. I have seen in other docs that perhaps the Beans.xml file needs to be updated, but it didn't seem like that was necessary in Quarkus.

Anyone see my error?

Is there a more effective way to achieve the effect of sending an event when the value is changed?

BTW, I tried just doing an ElementType.METHOD and annotating the Setter, but I got the same results.

Comment: The interceptor binding annotation on the interceptor must be present on the interceptor class, not on the method. You need to modify the `@Target` of the annotation and then put the annotation on the `DMNChangedInterceptor` class.

Comment: Yes. I did that and it starts. However, I want the Interceptor to only be able to be applied to methods. If I add the TYPE target then the user of the annotation could apply it to the entire class which is not the desired behavior. How do I restrict the usage to methods only?

Comment: In most cases that behaviour is an achivement. You can make this restriction manually in the method body like `(null == context.getMethod().getDeclaredAnnotation(DMNChanged.class))` => log warning or something.

Comment: It is common for interceptor binding annotations to be put on the class, which means all (non-private) methods are intercepted. I sympathize with anyone who doesn't like that, but that's the way it is.